# Sorting DevExpress GridControl by other column

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I bind a GridControl in server mode to an array of classes (`List<Product>`). Data is partially taken from a database, meaning that IDs are taken from the database, but then converted to names in the code (additional read-only properties).

Grid shows the names, not IDs. But when I click the grid header, I want to sort by IDs, i.e. if I click "Product Title" header, I actually want to sort by "Product ID".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort your List.

Try following:

```
myDataSource.Sort((x,y) => x.ProductID.CompareTo(y.ProductID));
myGridView.RefreshData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

Add `ID column` in the Grid View DataSource and Follow the links to implement sorting in the grid. There are few way to implement this. *You can use `Sorting` also*:

```
grid.Columns["ID"].SortOrder = ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
```

Or use `Custom Sorting` as below:

[Sorting Modes and Custom Sorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6142)

```
grid.ItemsSource = your list datasource;
grid.PopulateColumns();
grid.Columns[0].SortMode = ColumnSortMode.Custom;
grid.SortBy(grid.Columns[0]);
```

then handle the [GridControl.CustomColumnSort Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomColumnSorttopic):

```
private void grid_CustomColumnSort(object sender, CustomColumnSortEventArgs e) {
    e.Result = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(e.ListSourceRowIndex1,
        e.ListSourceRowIndex2);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

References:
[Sorting in Code](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6143)
[How to: Implement Custom Sorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6542)

Comment: Downvoter care to comment, so that other can get that what is wrong with the solution??